# Yii registerScript : Adding php parameters to javascript

Tags: javascript, php, yii, registerclientscriptblock

Hi I'm trying to use an external js, the and I'm using **Yii clienScript** :

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScriptFile(Yii::app()->baseUrl.'/js/some.js');
```

The problem is, in my external js file, **I need to pass a url**, for my ajax call. and the **url is in php,** because I'm using the **createAbsoluteUrl()** below :

```
$url = Yii::app()->createAbsoluteUrl("/module/controller/action")
```

**How do I pass the $url as a javascript variable** to be used by **some.js**? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a JS object at the end of your PHP code.

```
   ...
   ...
   $url = Yii::app()->createAbsoluteUrl("/module/controller/action");
   ...
   Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScriptFile(Yii::app()->baseUrl.'/js/some.js');
   <script>
   var WRAPPER = (WRAPPER || {});
   WRAPPER.url = "<?= $url ?>";
   </script>
```

Then the javascript file some.js should be able to use this as:

```
var url = WRAPPER.url;
```

I have done this on CodeIgniter - I'm assuming Yii works similar.